# How can i solve SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from entity error in c#?

Tags: c#, soap

I'm new in c# and try to call a web service with this code:

```
CRM.davoodkhorasani myCRM=new CRM.davoodkhorasani();
            myCRM.Timeout = int.MaxValue;
            var result= myCRM.BackRials("12", "IvR@123#MoQ@123");
```

but when i run that get this error:

```
SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from failed to load external entity
```

read any question and answer in stack over flow and dont understand any thing,how can i solve that error?thanks.

Comment: Can you share end of your web service url, something like `webservicename.svc?wsdl`

Comment: @IkramTurgunbaev http://ipaddress/webservice/CrmService.php?wsdl